# Is it possible to change 'radius' parameter in Transit Coverage Nearby in HERE maps?

Tags: here-api

I want to get a list of transit operators and station coverage near a location.
GET Request looks this way:

```
https://transit.api.here.com/v3/coverage/nearby.json?details=0&center=51.383574%2C12.381183&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ
```

Response:

```
'''{"Res": {
"serviceUrl": "https://transit.api.here.com/transit/v3/coverage/nearby.json",
"LocalCoverage": {
  "georef": "u30u",
  "NearbyCoverage": {
    "lines": 96,
    "stops": 43,
    "radius": 1965,
    "covered": 1,
    "type": "TT"
  }
}}}'''
```

When I'am trying to add parameter "radius" in URL it doesn't work. I am not good with REST API,
can anybody please advice, are there any opportunities? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the mandatory and optional parameters that can be passing transit API to fetch the response from API

> developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/resource-routing.html

Comment: ok, thank you, so there is no parameter "radius" for "Transit Coverage nearby", but there is one for "Find Station nearby"